# DocuSign Uploaded Attachment Action in History

Tags: docusignapi

I need to poll DocuSign for all envelopes where the signer uploaded an attachment.  I found a post suggesting listauditevents, but that is for one envelope ID.  I need to determine if we have completed envelopes where the signer printed and then uploaded the document.

I want to avoid downloading all of the envelopes' data and then looping through to find this action.

Is there an endpoint for actions that I am just not finding?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anytime you're thinking "polling", a better thought is to think "webhook." You can use the DocuSign webhook system (Connect) to be notified when an envelope is complete. Then check to see if an attachment was uploaded by a signer.

Easiest way to use webhooks and avoid the need to set up a server on the public internet is to use AWS et al to receive and queue the notification messages for your app (behind the firewall).

See

- [connect-node-listener-aws](https://github.com/docusign/connect-node-listener-aws)
- [connect-node-worker-aws](https://github.com/docusign/connect-node-worker-aws)
- and the other examples for Azure and Google Cloud. Plus, more examples are on their way for C#, Java, PHP, and Python

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I need to find out how many of the already completed opted to print and sign.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this info from the DocuSign online reports.  I customized the envelope recipient report to include 'signed on paper' column, downloaded the results to csv, opened in Excel and filtered where signed on paper = true.

Thank you for your suggestions and the use of this site.